Multiple standalone component in Angular
My problem
I am trying to load an Angular applications with multiple root-components, e.g.:
<body>
  <element-a></element-a>
  <element-b></element-b>
  <element-c></element-c>
</body>

I want to have multiple root-components instead of a single  because I would like to use them in an old legacy asp.net Framework website.
Previously I was able to get this done by bootstrapping my angular application with the following configuration code:
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(ElementAModule);
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(ElementBModule);
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(ElementCModule);

With the new guideline of the Angular-team that a component should be created as standalone, I was exited to try this out.
But the above bootstrap configuration only works for Modules and not for standalone components.
What I tried:
With bootstrapApplication I am able to load a standalone component as root.
It is even possible to load a second standalone component.
bootstrapApplication(ElementAComponent,{providers: [ ... ]})
  .then(
    appRef => appRef.bootstrap(ElementBComponent)
  );

However, this seems to be very sensitive for errors:

Sometimes it works (and renders the 2 components)
Sometimes it only renders 1 components,
Sometimes it renders 1 component and throws and error Error: The selector "element-B" did not match any elements

When I try to add a third component, the third component is never rendered at all.
bootstrapApplication(ElementAComponent,{providers: [ ... ]})
  .then(
    appRef => {
      appRef.bootstrap(ElementBComponent);
      appRef.bootstrap(ElementCComponent);
    }
  );

I found the following github issue, but it is closed without a clear solution for me:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/51331
In summary
Can I work with angular standalone components if I want to have multiple root components?
And if yes, what is the approach to take then?
Or should I stay away from this at this moment and keep working with the classic modules?

Firstly I think this is a bad idea, since you only need to bootstrap once, The best solution will be to have a wrapper component that contains all the child components and that will be loaded.
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [App1, App2, App3],
  template: `
    <app-root1/>
    <app-root2/>
    <app-root3/>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [provideRouter([])],
});

Stackblitz Demo
If you must do this, you just need bootstrapApplication called thrice. Once for each standalone root component.
const providers = [provideRouter([])];

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers,
});

bootstrapApplication(App1, {
  providers,
});

bootstrapApplication(App2, {
  providers,
});

Full Code:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root1',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
  `,
})
export class App1 {
  name = 'Angular';
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root2',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
  `,
})
export class App2 {
  name = 'Angular';
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

const providers = [provideRouter([])];

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers,
});

bootstrapApplication(App1, {
  providers,
});

bootstrapApplication(App2, {
  providers,
});

Stackblitz Demo

Most probably you need to look into Custom Elements (Web Components). You can create your Angular components as usual, but register them as custom elements. You can then attach your built JS files and then reference your components from any HTML rendered by asp.net. You can then pass data from the asp.net app to the web component and receive events from it. You might also find this article useful, as it discusses the very use case you are facing, while it is a bit dated, most concepts there are still applicable.
